# Angular - abort ajax request when using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a method that calls an angular service and consequently makes an ajax request via the service. I need to make sure that if this is called several times, the previous request in aborted (if it hasn't already been resolved that is).

This method can get called multiple times. This method is actually from ngTable on `ngTableParams`:

```
getData = function($defer, params) {

      myService.getRecord(params).then(function(res){ 
             ...
             $defer.resolve(res.Records);
      }); 
}
```

Here's the method on the service:

```
this.getRecords = function(params) {
    ...

    return Restangular
          .all('/api/records')
          .post(filters);
};
```

If ngTable makes 3 calls I want the first 2 to be aborted (unless of course they returned so fast that it got resolved)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can abort `$http` calls via the `timeout` config property, which can be a Promise, that aborts the request when resolved.

So in restangular, you can do this like

```
var abort = $q.defer();
Restangular.one('foos', 12345).withHttpConfig({timeout: abort.promise}).get();
abort.resolve();
```

To integrate it with your usecase, for example, you could have this in your service:

```
var abortGet;

this.getRecords = function(params) {
  ...
  if (abortGet) abortGet.resolve();
  abortGet = $q.defer();
  return Restangular
    .all('/api/records')
    .withHttpConfig({timeout: abortGet.promise})
    .post(filters);
}
```

This way calling `getRecords` always aborts the previous call if has not been resolved yet!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention but I already know it's done with a timeout promise. I included my own code because I don't see how it actually fits into my use case to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach if you want to abort all http requests when change the state for UI-router:

```
angular
    .run(function(HttpHandlerSrv) {
        HttpHandlerSrv.abortAllRequestsOn('$stateChangeSuccess');
        HttpHandlerSrv.R.setFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
            httpConfig = httpConfig || {};
            if(httpConfig.timeout === undefined) {
                httpConfig.timeout = HttpHandlerSrv.newTimeout();
            }
            return { element: element, params: params, headers: headers, httpConfig: httpConfig };
        });
    })

    .factory('HttpHandlerSrv', HttpHandlerSrv);


    /** ngInject */
    function HttpHandlerSrv($q, $rootScope, Restangular) {
        var requests = [];

        return {
            R: Restangular,
            newTimeout: newTimeout,
            abortAllRequests: abortAllRequests,
            abortAllRequestsOn: abortAllRequestsOn
        };

        function newTimeout() {
            var request = $q.defer();
            requests.push(request);
            return request.promise;
        }

        function abortAllRequests() {
            angular.forEach(requests, function(request) {
                request.resolve();
            });
            requests = [];
        }

        function abortAllRequestsOn(event) {
            $rootScope.$on(event, function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
                if(newUrl !== oldUrl) { abortAllRequests(); }
            });
        }
    }
```