# Cancel pending API calls in Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, promise, restangular

I have API service:

```
var SearchSuggestionApi = function (Restangular) {

  return {
    getSuggestion: function (keyword) {
      return Restangular.one('search').customGET(null, {keyword:keyword});
    }
  };

};

SearchSuggestionApi.$inject = [
  'Restangular'
];
```

I have controller to call this API:

```
vm.getSuggestion = function (keyword) {

  SearchSuggestionApi.getSuggestion(keyword)
    .then(
      function (data) {
        vm.listData = data;
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
};
```

My problem is when I call `vm.getSuggestion(keyword)` two or many time (must call than one time). Such as:

`vm.getSuggestion('a'); // => Return a array with many object in this`
`vm.getSuggestion('a b');// => Return empty array`

Because `vm.getSuggestion('a')` return many data, it will finish after `vm.getSuggestion('a b')`. So `vm.listData` is `[{object1}, {object2}, ...]`, but I want to `vm.listData` is `[]` (response data of the last function).

How can to cancel pending API call in first function when I call seconds function or another ways to get the last response data and set for `vm.listData`.

I researched some articles about `cancel pending API calls`, but it not help me about my problem.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of solving this:

- You can simply check in your then callback whether the value received is still current:

  ```
  vm.getSuggestion = function (keyword) {

    SearchSuggestionApi.getSuggestion(keyword)
      .then(
        function (data) {
          if (vm.keyword === keyword) {
              vm.listData = data;
          }
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
  };
  ```
- You can cancel the request by specifying a [timeout promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538772/angular-abort-ajax-request-when-using-restangular)
- If you are solving this problem often, you might wish to replace the promise by an [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/) observable stream with the appropriate operators. This is the cleanest solution, but does require an additional library.

Comment: I found solution is check `vm.keyword === keyword`, but I will accept your answer. Thanks so much :)